# rename file using matlab command

Tags: matlab

```
file1 = fullfile(pwd,'folder','toto.txt');
file2 = fullfile(pwd,'folder','toto2.txt.sav');

movefile(file1,file2)
```

=>this creates a folder named toto2.txt.sav 
whereas I'm looking for renaming the file in the same directory

any idea ?

Comment: It works for me.  What platform are you on?

Comment: Does it work without the `*`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/movefile.html#bt9yp61-2):

> **Renaming a File in the Current Folder**
>   In the current folder, rename myfunction.m to oldfunction.m:
>      movefile('myfunction.m','oldfunction.m')

Thus:

```
o=pwd
cd('folder')
movefile('toto.txt','toto2.txt.sav')
cd(o);
```

Comment: The documentation only includes this special use case (file in current folder, accessed via relative path) to rename. I don't know how Matlab determines if second parameter is a target directory or file name, thus I used this special case.

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for this as well. Now on a windows machine if I want to rename all files in a folder, I do:

```
system('rename *.* *.sav')
```

Comment: why using command that will not port well to other machines when you have a simple build-in function? This is not a good practice.

Comment: You could also say why try to remember a matlab function if this command works both in matlab, the console and python console for instance. But seeing your background and mine, you are probably right. I always find it difficult to remember these functions that you also have a console alternative for.